# Spring HATEOAS Hal Forms does not add current GET endpoint to the template section

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I am trying to build a template part of the Hal Forms (application/prs.hal-forms+json) and expect to have current GET endpoint being visible in a template part of this response. But it ignores any HttpMethod.GET affordances and they are not visible in that template.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/contact/some-participants")
public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<ClientDataDto>> getPersonInfoByPersonIdOrBankingId(@RequestParam(name = "personId", required = false) String personId,
                                                                                             @RequestParam(name = "bankingId", required = false) String bankingId) {

        PersonDataRetrievalController personDataRetrievalController = methodOn(PersonDataRetrievalController .class);
        Link link = Affordances.of(linkTo(personDataRetrievalController.getPersonInfoByPersonIdOrBankingId(personId, bankingId)).withSelfRel())
                .afford(HttpMethod.GET)
                .withOutput(ClientDataDto.class) //
                .withName("getPartnerInfoByPersonIdOrBankingId")

                .andAfford(HttpMethod.POST)
                .withOutput(ClientDataDto.class)
                .withName("changePartner")
                .addParameters(
                        QueryParameter.required("id")
                )
                .andAfford(HttpMethod.DELETE)
                .withOutput(Object.class)
                .withName("deletePartner")
                .addParameters(
                        QueryParameter.required("id")
                )
                .toLink();

        Optional<ClientDataDto> clientData = Optional.of(constructClientDataDto());
        CollectionModel<ClientDataDto> collectionModel = CollectionModel.of(Collections.singletonList(clientData.get()));
        collectionModel.add(link);

        return clientData.map(data -> new ResponseEntity<>(collectionModel, HttpStatus.OK))
                .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
    }
```

POST and DELETE affordances were added just to show that other HttpMethod(s) are represented. As a result I am getting response as:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "clientDataDtoList": [
            {
                "personFullName": "personFullName",
                "language": "language",
                "personId": "personId"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/clientData/contact/some-participants{?personId,bankingId}",
            "templated": true
        }
    },
    "_templates": {
        "default": {
            "method": "post",
            "properties": []
        },
        "deletePartner": {
            "method": "delete",
            "properties": []
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to have also current GET method to be represented in this template part of the response. Actually it does not work with any HttpMethod.GET affordances, not only with the current one for me. E.g. when I use code from official Spring docs like:

```
.andAfford(HttpMethod.GET) 
    .withOutput(Employee.class) //
    .addParameters(//
        QueryParameter.optional("name"), //
        QueryParameter.optional("role")) //
    .withName("search") /
```

It also does not show this part in the template.
Also I will appreciate, if someone knows how to remove

```
"templated": true
```

part from the Link section.

Comment: Hi @user3111411,

1. I just stumbled on gets being filtered too. I can see the code for it in `HalFormsTemplateBuilder.findTemplates()`. I don't know why. Perhaps it's part of the HAL-FORMS spec? 

2. The `templated` property makes sense because your link has `{?personId,bankingId}` which means there are additional values that are required for this link to work.

Comment: In the spec they don't seem to mention that a specific method is required
https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/#_code_method_code. Oliver Drotbohm helped me with another question on HAL-FORMS recently. Maybe he'll see this? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/18122/oliver-drotbohm